# Why is this Javascript not enabling this text box (aspx)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Thanks for taking a second to look at this. I know to most of you client side scripting this is an easy one. Anyway, I simply just want to have a message at the top alerting the user that their click was registered and to disable the button.

<----CODE BELOW---->

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="content">
<div>
    <asp:TextBox BorderStyle="None" Font-Bold="True" Height="15" Width="300"
                    ForeColor="Green" runat="server" ID="MessageBox" Visible="False" Text="Archiving compliance results..."></asp:TextBox>
</div>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

  <Table STUFF!> ....
                    <span>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="ArchiveImageButton" runat="server" AlternateText="Archive Compliance"
                            ImageUrl="~/images/Icons/24/452-bank.gif" OnClientClick="archiveIt()" OnClick="btnArchive_Click" ToolTip="Archive compliance results" />
                    </span>
  </Table STUFF!>
</table>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function archiveIt() {
        window.ArchiveImageButton.enabled = false;
        window.MessageBox.visible = true;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You can't do that. You have set the textbox control to be invisible on the server side, so it's not rendered to the page. You can show something that doesn't exist at all. Besides, Javascript uses the `disabled` property to determine if an element is enabled or not, not `enabled`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two problems.  First, you need to use `getElementById` to get the element.  `window.ElementId` won't work:

```
var element = document.getElementById('myId');
```

Second, your controls have *server side IDs*.  The IDs will be different when they're rendered down to the client.  There's two ways to fix that.  One, get the `ClientID` property:

```
var element = document.getElementById('<%= MyControl.ClientID %>');
```

Or two, set the `ClientIDMode` to static on the control:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="MyTextBox" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="Server" />
```

Then you can use:

```
var element = document.getElementById('MyTextBox');
```

Also, note that an `<input>` control doesn't have a `visible` property.  You'll probably want `.style.display`.

So, your code should probably look something like:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function archiveIt() {
        document.getElementById('<%= ArchiveImageButton.ClientID %>').enabled = false;
        document.getElementById('<%= MessageBox.ClientID %>').style.display = 'inherit';
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The ID is probably not what you expect; ASP wraps IDs with their container (like `Container_ActiveImageButton`). How about something like:

```
<script>
  function archiveIt(){
    var aib = document.getElementById('<%= this.ArchiveImageButton.ClientID; %>');
    aib.enabled = false;
  }
</script>
```

Alternatively you can play with [`ClientIDMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx) on the control and made it [`Static`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientidmode.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the `ClientIDMode` to `Static` on both controls to avoid having extra stuff on the their ID